# Google Translate Text to Speech from a variable

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech

The scenario is im getting a input from the user and need to give audio for that text.The imput from the user is stored in a variable. How to give the value of the variable to Google tts

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
function myfunction()
{
$("#div_style").html($("#text_area_id").val());
if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
  {
  localStorage.lase=$("#text_area_id").val();
  document.getElementById("div_style").innerHTML=" " + localStorage.lase;

var audio = new Audio();
audio.src ='http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=en&q=localStorage.lase;
audio.play();
 }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform"> 
<textarea name="text_area" id="text_area_id" rows="2" cols="16"></textarea>
</form> 

<input type="button" onclick="myfunction()" value="save" />
<div style="color:red" id="div_style">
</div>is certified.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing to do with Java. -1 for not reading the helpful tag pop-ups.

Comment: @AndrewThompson okies. Can u pls help for this?

Comment: *"Can u pls help for this?"*  Please use the correct spelling for words like 'you', 'your' & 'please'.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Comment: @AndrewThompson sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try appending the variable:

```
audio.src ='http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=en&q=' + localStorage.lase;
```

If it works with strings, it should work.

Comment: With regular text it does? if you add 'hello world' as the q parameter value.

Comment: I want to see the URL you use with regular text, which you say works. can you add it?

Comment: sorry i dont understand what you are asking. Im just using this single html file. try copying it and using it

Comment: anyways thanks a lot for trying to help. I dont have much knowledge in this so couldnt answer :(

Comment: You say that regular text works, right? I want to check the differences between the working code and the not-working code. For this I need the working code.

Comment: Appending the variable is just the same. Try do it when the variable holds a simple string (no white spaces or complex characters).